# Getting exception "No output operations registered, so nothing to execute" from Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, spark-structured-streaming

```
package com.scala.sparkStreaming

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

object Demo1 {
  def main(assdf:Array[String]){

     val sc=new SparkContext("local","Stream")

     val stream=new StreamingContext(sc,Seconds(2))

     val rdd1=stream.textFileStream("D:/My Documents/Desktop/inbound/sse/ssd/").cache()

     val mp1= rdd1.flatMap(_.split(","))
     print(mp1.count())

     stream.start()
     stream.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

I had run it, then it shows an exception

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@6342993220/05/22 18:14:16 ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:576)
    at com.scala.sparkStreaming.Demo1$.main(Demo1.scala:18)
    at com.scala.sparkStreaming.Demo1.main(Demo1.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:576)
    at com.scala.sparkStreaming.Demo1$.main(Demo1.scala:18)
    at com.scala.sparkStreaming.Demo1.main(Demo1.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "No output operations registered, so nothing to execute" gives a hint that something is missing.

Your Direct Streams `rdd1` and `mp1` do not have any *Action*. A `flatMap` is only a *Transformation* which gets lazily evaluated by Spark. That is why the `stream.start()` method throws this Exception.

According to the documentation, you can [print out an RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd) as shown below. As you are dealing with a DStream you could iterator through the RDDs. Below code runs fine with Spark version 2.4.5.

The documentation of `textFileStream` says that it "monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem for **new files** and reads them as text files", so make sure that you add/modify the file you want to read *while* the job is running.

Also, although I am not completely familiar with Spark on Windows, you may need to change the directory string to

```
file://D:\\My Documents\\Desktop\\inbound\\sse\\ssd
```

Here is the full code example for Spark Streaming:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object Main extends App {
  val sc=new SparkContext("local[1]","Stream")

  val stream=new StreamingContext(sc,Seconds(2))

  val rdd1 =stream.textFileStream("file:///path/to/src/main/resources")

  val mp1= rdd1.flatMap(_.split(" "))

  mp1.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.collect().foreach(println(_)))

  stream.start()
  stream.awaitTermination()
}
```

In Spark version 2.4.5 `Spark Streaming` is deprecated and I would suggest to get familiar already with `Spark Structured Streaming`. The code for that would look something like this:

```
// Structured Streaming
  val lines: DataFrame = spark.readStream
    .format("text")
    .option("path", "file://path/to/src/main/resources")
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", "1")
    .load()

  val query = lines.writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .start()

  query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: I had tried above line.It worked,but it prints nothing in the console.

Comment: Thanks @mike for you effort.I will check that.